# Inverted a Responsive Size for an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to use the following design on a responsive website. I'm curious if there's a way to set up some sort of inverse resizing method through jQuery / Javascript because as the viewport gets smaller, the copy will respond and get **larger**.

I've tried using jQuery to modify the image size, but I only know enough to manually resize it at different breakpoints

Here's my attempt at a solution:

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

if (viewportWidth <= 768) {
$("#curlybrace").css("width", "80px");
}
```

Is there a way to set up a dynamic scaling image?
[image: Curly Brace Beside Copy Block]

Comment: have you try using CSS media query ?   check this link for better understand http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: what is not working with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into CSS and media queries, seems like it would be a neater solution than trying to do this with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like this:

```
 function resizeFn() {
   var width = window.width();
   // ...
 }

 $(function() {
   $(window).resize(resizeFn).trigger('resize');
 });
```

Not possible to do an inverse with CSS, I don't think (I thought maybe through calc(), but I don't think it lets you do unit manipulations like that).

Fair warning, this doesn't sound like a good design unless you're trying to make it look nuts.